# Generative Adversarial Network doesn't generate recognizable patterns

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, generator, discriminator

I tried to build a generative adversarial network with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
from PIL import Image

d_epochs = 10
g_epochs = 10

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

batch_size = 9

x_train = []
y_train = []

for filename in glob.glob('trainig_data/*.jpg'):
    im = mpimg.imread(filename)
    x_train.append(im)
    y_train.append(1.0)
    if len(x_train) == 396:
        break

gen_seed = np.random.rand(396)

g_input = 1
g_hidden1 = 100
g_hidden2 = 100
g_hidden3 = 116412

g_weights = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([g_input,                                                                                                                                                                         g_hidden1])),
                 tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([g_hidden1, g_hidden2])),
                 tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([g_hidden2, g_hidden3])),
                 tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,3])),
                 tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,3])),
                 tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,3]))]

def generator(x, weights):
    output=tf.matmul([[x]], weights[0])
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.matmul(output, weights[1])
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.matmul(output, weights[2])
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.reshape(output, [1,218,178,3])
    output=tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[3], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[4], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[5], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    return output[0]

d_weights = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,3])),
             tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,3])),
             tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,3])),
             tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([261927, 100])),
             tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 100])),
             tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 2]))]

def discriminator(x, weights):
    output=tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights[0], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[1], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[2], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.reshape(output, [261927])
    output=tf.matmul([output], weights[3])
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.matmul(output, weights[4])
    output=tf.nn.relu(output)
    output=tf.matmul(output, weights[5])
    output=tf.reduce_mean(output)
    return(output)

prediction = discriminator(x, d_weights)
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(prediction + 1e-12))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
g_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(-prediction)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for e in range(d_epochs):
        print('epoch:', e+1)
        for b in range(int(len(x_train)/batch_size)):
            start = b*batch_size
            end = start+batch_size
            batch_x = x_train[start:end]
            batch_y = y_train[start:end]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer,loss],feed_dict={y:batch_y, x:batch_x})
    saver.save(sess, 'saved/discriminator.ckpt')

    file = 0
    for e in range(g_epochs):
        print('epoch:', e+1)
        for b in range(int(len(gen_seed)/batch_size)):
            file += 1
            preds = []
            fake = []
            start = b*batch_size
            end = start+batch_size
            batch = gen_seed[start:end]
            for i in batch:
                fake.append(sess.run(generator(i, g_weights)))
            sess.run([prediction, loss, optimizer, g_optimizer], feed_dict={x:fake, y:np.zeros(len(fake))})
            im = Image.fromarray(fake[0].astype('uint8'))
            im.save('output/'+str(file)+'.png')
    saver.save(sess, '/saved/generator.ckpt')
```

But even after 10 epochs (440 batches) of training the generator, the patterns it generates aren't coherent at all (I will include an example Image).
Please help me fix this issue.
PS. I am using the Images of the CelebA dataset if that helps.[image]

Comment: your `generator` function is not proper, you need to use `upsampling` ops like `tf.nn.conv2d_transposed`. A good implementation of recent GAN https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow

Comment: I replaced every `tf.nn.conv2d` with `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` but now it returns
` fake.append(sess.run(generator(i, g_weights)))
  File "D:\Kay\Tensorflow\Session 5\GAN\GAN.py", line 47, in generator
    output=tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(output, weights[3], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
  File "C:\Users\Katharina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1034, in conv2d_transpose
    "{} != {}".format(output_shape[axis], filter.get_shape()[2]))
ValueError: output_shape does not match filter's output channels, 1 != 3`